# Best scheduling practice using VC++ for capture in directshow 

Tags: visual-c++, video, directshow, video-capture, timing

I have one capture application, that performs the `MP4` capture. i need to schedule this capture application to capture video of every 30 minutes (or some dynamic value).

I read the MSDN article for `IReferenceClock::AdviseTime` from article i am not sure but i assume will trigger event when end-time elapses. but it not seems to work . please advice me if my understanding is incorrect about it. Or is any other batter way to repeat schedule in 30 minutes to capture video??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`IReferenceClock::AdviseTime` is what let's close schedule setting an event. Filters might take advantage of this internally as a part of streaming operation. For you, however, this methods is of no use. There is a number of ways to trigger an action every 30 minutes. On a running application you would typically use `SetTimer` + `WM_TIMER` API. If you want your app started every 30 minutes, Task Scheduler is here for you.

Comment: Thanks @Roman for your reply. i come to know that SetTimer do not provide very good precision, what other we can use to provide precision??

Comment: You did not mention that you need specific high precision. What precision you need?

Comment: Not sure about the reason why you need this precision, however there is no timer to be that accurate. You might want to prefer to capture video continuously, and then use timestamps to cut at the right place - to stop file and start new (this is not possible within plain single graph though).

Comment: we will do 2 graphs start new and then stop first... but what can be best schedule practice??

Comment: The best is to keep smooth capture in out graph without stopping it and pass data into separate writing graph. Some use bridges http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/, some prefer implementing custom data delivery between the graphs. Restarting capture graph you are way behind the desired timing accuracy.

Comment: Thanks @Roman R. for your reply, i'll lookout into [gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge](http://gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge). and we will not restart capture , but will Start a new Capture Graph  and after that starts ,will stop old capture graph, what accuracy you think it will give?? how much we behind??

Comment: As logn as you don't interrupt capture, you don't have to worry about the timing. All media data is time stamped, so your recording does not have to have real time precision to preserve time accuracy. To give you a clue, well written code is operating at accuracy of a few milliseconds depending on system load and running applications.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11743/discussion-between-meghana-and-roman-r)